# When is it appropriate to edit someone else's question?

Tags: discussion

In connection with [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/15831/3440) which is now "on hold", there is the message "If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, *please edit the question* or leave a comment."  Although I think the question has already been adequately edited to get it re-opened, I seem to be the only one voting for that.   **Is it appropriate for anyone other than the author to edit the question even more?** (It risks mis-stating the author's intentions.) I happen to think it's actually a nice code-challenge problem, and would like to see what other solutions people might have.

Comment: Not an answer, but it's a boring trivial question which treads no new ground. It's just a base conversion between base 24 and base 64.

Answer (score 2):

*This whole post is just my opinion as a Stack Exchange user, and I am not speaking as a moderator here, and definitely not "the moderator who closed the linked question at the request of another user".*

I believe that [posts are okay to be edited by anyone](/help/editing), especially if (on this site) it makes it a more suitable or fair or accessible golfing/coding challenge. Of course, for substantial edits, it's more polite to propose edits as a comment first, and gather community consensus, but once such consensus is reached, I believe it's okay to edit the post directly.

If the author of a question feels like an edit misrepresented their ideas or positions, they are free to make further edits. So don't worry about that.

Comment: This about covers it.